# Streamlit app does not display data obtained from python socket

Tags: python, sockets, streamlit

I used the following code:

```
import socket
import struct
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st


UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 9000

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    fields = struct.unpack_from('=ddd', data)
    
    d = {'y': fields[0],
         'x': fields[1],
         'z': fields[2]}

    df = pd.DataFrame([d], columns=d.keys())

    df
```

The app does not display the dataframe (see below). What is the best way to deal with socket data to use in the app? The data is generated 1/60th of a second. I can reduce the frequency to 0.2 s but I don't know how to do that via `socket`.

[image]

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with streamlit.

Comment: @ferdy Thank you. What does it have to do then?

Comment: If your df has data, try `st.write(df)`

Comment: While not a solution, this may help: https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/using-session-state-within-socketio-client-events/45774/2